# Google API country detect PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, ip, google-api

How can I get country with Google API? I have seen Javascript version. But I need to get by PHP. How can I get this?

I need most simple and fast way to get Country in PHP.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Geocoding API Web Service and cURL in php, you'll be able to pass a url through with the right parameters to return, either in json or xml, the result that you want.

See:

- [Google Geocoding API Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)
- [PHP.net cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: it seems that you can get only by Address. other way to do this via IP?